# vue3: how to add vuex files to vue-docgen-cli generate?

Tags: vuejs3, vuex, vue-styleguidist

I'm trying to add documentation for the store, I found an example (https://github.com/vue-styleguidist/vue-styleguidist/tree/dev/examples/vuex) and want to adapt it to Vue3

docgen.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    ...
    renderRootJsx: path.join('docs', '.vitepress/styleguide.root.js')
}
```

styleguide.root.js

```
import { h } from 'vue'
import { useStore } from 'vuex'

export default previewComponent => {
    const store = useStore()
    return {
        store,
        render() {
            return h(previewComponent)
        }
    }
}
```

no result